# Google Clould Message demo setup : Dependencies not found

Tags: android, dependencies, google-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate GCM into my android app. For the beginning I wanted to test the GCM demo that comes with the Google tutorial on how to use GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

I downloaded the demo project an imported it into my ADT eclipse. So this is what I did:

1. I downloaded the "Google Play services" via SDK Manager and additionally "Google Repository"
2. I copied the "/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/" into my workspace (as recommended by the tutorial)
3. On the following screenshot you can see that I added the copy of "google-play-services_lib" as a Library to the GCM demo project[image]
4. However, the dependencies are not resolved as the following screenshot shows:
   [image]

So at what point in the instructions chain did I make an error?

Comment: Select `Project Build Target` as `Google APIs 2.3.3`

Comment: @toom where is GCM.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play Services doesn't contain `GCMRegistrar` class. That class is part of the deprecated GCM Client library. Instead of using `GCMRegistrar`, use `com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging` class to register to GCM.

You are using an old version of the GCM Demo. Try the [current version here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow GCM sample code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/)